# Have professional dreamers been explored in the Alien franchise?

Tags: alien-franchise, dreams

In the Alan Dean Foster novelisation of the film *Alien*, the book starts off with:

> Seven dreamers.
>
> You must understand that they were not professional dreamers.
> Professional dreamers are highly paid, respected, much sought-after talents.
> Like the majority of us, these seven dreamt without effort or discipline. Dreaming professionally, so that one’s dreams can be recorded and played
> back for the entertainment of others, is a much more demanding
> proposition.

Has the concept of professional dreamers been explored further in the Alien franchise?

The nearest that supports this possibility I have found is from *Prometheus*, where, near the beginning, David was observing Elizabeth Shaw's dreams.

Comment: Never mentioned again, if memory serves. And purely an invention of Foster's.

Comment: Sounds like Foster is referencing Asimov's "Dreaming is a Private Thing" which did have professional dreamers.